# Access LinkedIn user home or news feed

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am attempting to gain access to the news feed or home in a user's LinkedIn profile using the LinkedIn Developer APIs.

When I went through [LinkedIn Developer documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs), I haven't been able to discover a proper reference to a doc associated with this feature.

Does this suggest that we have to be a LinkedIn certified API partner to achieve this target? If not, where can I find an appropriate documentation for this.

Comment: You cannot access LinkedIn user's feed through Rest API. There is no proper documentation available without the registration.

Comment: In this case registration refers to being a LinkedIn certified API partner?

Comment: Yes. LinkedIn certified API partner.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will check that out.

Comment: I found this please checkout:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/share-and-social-stream/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api